# Android emulator 7.0 with play store not starting up - "Decryption unsuccessful"

Tags: android, emulation

I am encountering this problem with the version of Android emulator where when I launch it will normally boot up and ask for a password (which the other emulator images do not, not sure what is up with that).

[image]

After I enter any kind of password to it, the following screen pops up

[image]

If I click the reset phone button the phone will boot up again to the password screen, and after entering password the same decryption unsuccessful screen will show up.

I have tried removing the virtual device and re-downloading the system image but that did not seem to help. The other system images seem to work fine, though this is the only system image with the play store installed that I have tried (are there even other images?). I'm using the api level 24 x86 system image that shows up in the recommended system images. I'm trying to use the emulator on Windows 10 64bit system.

Comment: Most likely the Android image you're using is encrypted. Can you provide a link to this image?

Comment: @m0skit0 I sadly can't, I downloaded it through Android Studio's AVD Manager. I don't think they are available through other channels.

Comment: You mean SDK Manager? Which image exactly?

Comment: Well yeah, I guess the AVD manager refers to the SDK manager. The Android 7.0 (Google Play) x86 image is the one I'm trying to use. For me it is in the recommended tab instead of the x86 Images tab when looking at the Virtual Device Configuration (through AVD's Create Virtual Device... button)

Comment: That should not happen. Make sure you are running v26.1.0 of the Android Emulator and revision 12 of the Google Play version of the Emulator System Image for API 24.  If there are update on either one of those, create a new image.  Also note, we have Google Play images for Android O system images as well. If those does not work, please send us ( the Android Emulator team) a bug report, but going to: Emulator Tool Bar → Extended Controls → Help → Emulator Help → File a Bug

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I downloaded the Canary 2 of the AS 3.0 so I could get the emulator version 26.1.0 (update was not appearing for me on the 2.3.2 of AS), and re-created the image, but this did not seem to help, I already had the revision 12 of the Google Play image. I also tried out the O Google Play image but it does the same thing as the 7.0 one. I'll file a bug report for you, hopefully you can figure out what is wrong with it.

Comment: Hi! Did you find a solution? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @Daniela sadly not, I haven't been able to use the play images for testing at all.

Comment: My emulator with Android O Google play is not starting up. Please help if anyone has any solution